# Find the joint distribution of a discrete and a continuous random variable

Tags: statistics

Let $P$ be a gamma random variable with parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$. We know that the conditional distribution of the random variable X given $P=p$ is a Bernoulli random variable. Find the marginal distribution of $X$.

I know that to compute the marginal distribution of $X$ I need the joint probability distribution of $X$ and $P$. Now,

$f_{x|p}(x|p)=\frac{f_{x,p}(x,p)}{f_p(p)}$, so that

$f_{x,p}(x,p)=f_{x|p}(x|p) f_p(p)$.

The problem is that $f_{x|p}(x|p)$ is a discrete random variable and $f_p(p)$ is a continuous random variable, so what happens with the product? And how to compute the marginal distribution?

Is it $f_x(x)=\int f_{x,p}(x,p) dp$ (if so, what are the limits?) or $f_x(x)=\sum_{p} f_{x,p}(x,p)$.

Comment: Are you saying that $P\sim \Gamma(\alpha, \beta)$, and $X|P=p \sim Ber(p)$? Note that, $P\in (0,\infty)$. If so, What it means if $p>1$?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. I guess $p$ is this case is restricted to $p\in (0,1)$. This problem is part of an optional problem set in my Stats class, but maybe the question is wrong.

Comment: Another interpretation could be that if $p>1$, then $X$ is a sure event, given that occurs with probability 1.

Comment: In general, because you are integrating w.r.t to $P$, and $P$ is continuous r.v, you should integrate $\int_{S}f_{X|p}(x|p)f_P(p)dp$, where $S=(0,\infty)$. But since, $p\in [0,1]$, otherwise $X|P=p$ quite meaningless, I'm not sure what are the required modifications.